# Entity Framework Include will Lazy Load if I add a Where Clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF 6.1.3.  My original task was for a query to return all articles, their Tags and Sections, and the Sections' Paragraphs.  I **had** this query and it worked fine:

```
using (SuaContext context = new SuaContext())
{
    var ret = (
        from x in context.Articles
            .Include(y => y.Sections.Select(z => z.Paragraphs))
            .Include(y => y.Tags)
        select x
    ).ToList();
    return ret;
}
```

The consuming code can then access all children or grandchildren navigation property data and I'm happy.

But I no longer want all articles, I just want articles that contain a particular tag.  The relationship is a many to many with a join table. `Article > ArticleToTag < ArticleTag`.  So I added these two lines:

```
using (SuaContext context = new SuaContext())
{
    var ret = (
        from x in context.Articles
            .Include(y => y.Sections.Select(z => z.Paragraphs))
            .Include(y => y.Tags)
        from t in x.Tags                      // Added this
        where t.ArticleTagType == specificTag // And this
        select x
    ).ToList();
    return ret;
}
```

If I break on `return ret`, everything looks correct.  That is, if I observe the variable while still within the using block, the children and grandchildren navigation properties are evaluated.  And after observing all properties, I can F5 and all my code works fine.

But if I don't manually observe the properties here, then the consuming code throws the dreaded ObjectExposedException "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed" when a consumer tries to access those properties.

Comment: Why did you also add `from t in x.Tags`? What do you think it does? Why didn't you just add `where x.Tags.Any(t => t.ArticleTagType == specificTag)`?

Comment: Because apparently I have lost my mind and all of my problems are solved now.  Moral: Don't post on S.O. when you have 102 fever.  >.<  That solved my issue.

Comment: Just go to bed then. :P

Comment: Consider it done.  If you make an answer that says "go to bed and your code will work tomorrow."  I'll check that.